# Get-ADuser attribute 'businesscategory'

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to export a list that oulines the attribute 'businesscategory'.

Here is the command:

```
ipmo activedirectory

get-aduser -Filter * -Properties * | select userprincipalname, businesscategory |export-csv -Path C:\Temp\businesscategory.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

The thing is that I get this output under the row 'businesscategory' in my .csv :

"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"

The output is good in the Powershell console though.

I have looked for answers around the Internet but unsuccessfully so far...

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

It's a multivalued property so you have to create a new property and concatenate the values or select one of them

```
get-aduser -filter * -Properties * | select userprincipalname, @{n="businesscategory";e={$_.businesscategory -join " "}}
```

then it will be exported as a string in your csv.

Comment: Just for ease of reading once it's in the spreadsheet I would either comma delimit it with the join, or comma space like `-join ', '`.

Comment: Ok thank you guys. But as you can see I have piped the values in order to keep the information UPN and businesscategory. There is something else...

Comment: @Charlypop I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Apologies @Adam! I did not read your comment entirely. Your command works!

Comment: But how did you come to this : @{n="businesscategory";e={$_.businesscategory -join " "}}

Comment: I need to understand ;)